# The correct why to debug dask.dataframe.to_parquet

Tags: dask, fastparquet

I've seen that there are some issues with the type of column objects when running the `to_parquet` function.  I'm running dask version 15.1 .

I've explicitly converted my columns using the [astype(object)](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.astype), which helped with some columns but not all.
I'm getting the following error -  `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`.
After adding the `object_encoding='utf-8` parameter I'm getting the following error - `TypeError: expected list of bytes` .

What would be the best way to debug this issue?
BTW- My dataset has Hebrew characters.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The correct spelling is `object_encoding='utf8'`.

Note that the object encoding is generally a per-column setting, so you could have for instance `object_encoding={'a': 'utf8', 'b': 'bytes'}`. The special value `'infer'` tries to guess the correct encoding for a given object column, but it is not always successful in doing that; this is presumably the cause of the first error you see.

Comment: Thx for your answer - however I'm still getting the error -  `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`  even though I've used the explicit `{'colname':'utf8' ...}`

Comment: The error arises when utf8-encoding something that isn't a string, you should check your column of data and ensure it contains only strings and None.

Comment: Before running the `to_parquet` I'm verifying that it is an object using the `dd.col1 = dd.col1.astype(object)` , and there are no nulls using (checked with the `isnull()`). I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The question is, are all elements *strings*?

Comment: Like `df['colname'].map(type).value_counts()`